# Cloud Server to run Java Code

Tags: java, cloud, artificial-intelligence

I am doing research in AI field for a Computer Science degree. I have written a Java program to run a lot of simulations. On my i7 desktop it took almost a day to run all the simulations once. I would like to run them multiple times to get accurate averages. All the input files are specified in txt files and output are also in txt files. The program does not require large disk space nor RAM but a lot of processing power.

What cloud platform is the simplest(I would like just to upload the code and click run) and cheapest for me to run these simulations on?

Any suggestions from someone who has used a service like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Cloudbees or OpenShift

They are free and easy to use.
Click ..Upload.. Run!!

Comment: Thank you. I am tying them now

Comment: Cool.. best of luck .. Cloudbees is easier..!!